# How to know last modified user from login page and displaying in login page label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I make login page with access database i have many forms but I need code when one user login and make changes in forms then the modified user name comes in label on login page and when I close project then again execute that user name written in label.

[This is login page get data from database with access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK6aN.jpg)
[On second image if any user which is logged changed the data or entering new data then how that user name show on login page in label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfefD.jpg)

Comment: Show what you try.

Comment: The question is not clear can you provide more details?

Comment: now you check images you easily understand

Comment: @SabirAliKhuhro what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Artiom I make project of examination management system I make login page and with many other forms but i need code when user login and changes in any form so the name of user written when i again execute project on label in login page

Comment: please someone help me no one understand problem then why you're here?????